JS Variable outside function / global var
probably a stupid/very simple question but I can't figure it out. I get the sat_id from an API, which I want to append to a new API URL. So I need the sat_id outside the function. How do I do that?
Here is the script:
const sat_url = 'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites';
let sat_id = 0; 

async function getISS() {
           const response  = await fetch(sat_url);
           const data = await response.json();
           sat_id = data[0].id;
           console.log(sat_id); //here is the correct sat_id
}

getISS();

console.log(sat_id); //here ist the "0" from above but not the sat_id from the function

const data_url ='https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/' + sat_id;

translate by google :)

instead of "console.log(sat_id) ":
"return sat_id" and then:
"sat_id = getISS()".
it this enough?

@Antek No, it's not.

so, you can use "var" instead of "let". But i  think the problem is with your async, try to call it in IIFE: "(async() => {  await getISS(); /** here next request*/})()
